# Wrapped image max-height, looking for another solution

Tags: css

Although code is very symetric, my image changes size when I narrow window on width but nothing happens on window height change. Probably I understand what is mistake but I don't see any solution.

```css
div {
  max-width: 50vw;
  max-height: 50vh;
}
img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src='http://imgsv.imaging.nikon.com/lineup/lens/zoom/normalzoom/af-s_dx_18-300mmf_35-56g_ed_vr/img/sample/sample4_l.jpg'>Notes
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify `width` and `height` values for the wrapper div

[**JS Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/3xfhy8qs/) << resize the result panel horizontally and vertically  to see the behavior.

```css
div {
  width: 50vw;
  height: 50vh;
}
img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src='http://imgsv.imaging.nikon.com/lineup/lens/zoom/normalzoom/af-s_dx_18-300mmf_35-56g_ed_vr/img/sample/sample4_l.jpg'>Notes
</div>
```